# Has Child join field issue

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Good day:

I've setup a Parent/Child relationship model between `Facility` and `FacilityType`. Currently I'm trying to query the `Facility` and at the same time trying to load the children by using the `HasChild` query but, I'm getting the following error:

```
 {  
   "aggs":{  
      "Capacity":{  
         "children":{  
            "type":"facilitytype"
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "Capacity":{  
               "histogram":{  
                  "field":"capacity",
                  "interval":10.0,
                  "missing":0.0
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "Distance":{  
         "histogram":{  
            "field":"businessLocation",
            "interval":10.0,
            "order":{  
               "_count":"desc"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "should":[  
            {  
               "bool":{  
                  "must":[  
                     {  
                        "geo_distance":{  
                           "boost":1.1,
                           "distance":"200.0m",
                           "distance_type":"arc",
                           "businessLocation":{  
                              "lat":38.958878299999988,
                              "lon":-77.365260499999991
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     {  
                        "has_child":{  
                           "_name":"FacilityType",
                           "type":"doc",
                           "query":{  
                              "match_all":{  

                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {  
               "geo_distance":{  
                  "boost":1.1,
                  "distance":"200.0m",
                  "distance_type":"arc",
                  "serviceAreas":{  
                     "lat":38.958878299999988,
                     "lon":-77.365260499999991
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I'm getting this error when I execute the query:

```
[has_child] join field [joinField] doesn't hold [doc] as a child
```